# How can I add elements to an ArrayList of objects outside a method

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to make a multiple-choice quiz program. The QuizQuestion class works with Question objects and holds methods for setting the text on the question label and answer-buttons in the GUI class each time the user presses the "Next Question" button.

My problem is that after the last Question object in the ArrayList is displayed it starts with the first element again instead of finishing the quiz. I understand that the reason is the getCurrentQuestion() method where I add the Question objects into the ArrayList, so that each time the method gets called the same elements are added into the ArrayList again.

How could I solve this problem and still access each Question variable by ArrayList index in my getCurrentQuestion() and getCurrentAnswers() methods?
Is there a way to add my Question objects into the ArrayList outside of a method? Any help would be appreciated.

This is an example of what I'm trying to do:

The QuizQuestion class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class QuizQuestion {


public int currentQuestionIndex = 0;
public String userAns;
public int correctAnswers;


public ArrayList<Question> questionBank = new ArrayList<Question>();

 Question question1 = new Question("What is 4 + 8", Arrays.asList("11", "14", "12"), "12");
 Question question2 = new Question("What is 24 - 7", Arrays.asList("17", "13", "16"), "17");
 Question question3 = new Question("What is 7 * 9", Arrays.asList("72", "63", "56"), "63");




public String getCurrentQuestion() {
    String question;
    questionBank.add(question1);
    questionBank.add(question2);
    questionBank.add(question3);
    question = questionBank.get(currentQuestionIndex).getQuestion();

    return question;
}


public List<String> getCurrentAnswers() {
    List <String> answrs;

    answrs = questionBank.get(currentQuestionIndex).getAnswers();
    return answrs;
}



}
```

Then in my GUI class I have a method that gets called each time the user clicks the "Next" button:

```
 QuizQuestion quiz = new QuizQuestion();


 public void nextQuestion() {

    quiz.currentQuestionIndex = quiz.currentQuestionIndex + 1;
        label.setText(quiz.getCurrentQuestion()); 
        setButtons(quiz.currentQuestionIndex); //sets the text for possible answers on Radiobuttons.



    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question, you don't expect us to read all that or, do you ?

Comment: If you want to add to the arraylist outside of a method, you can either make it public to the class or just make a method that'll add to the list

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that after the last Question object in the ArrayList is
>   displayed it starts with the first element again instead of finishing
>   the quiz. I understand that the reason is the getCurrentQuestion()
>   method where I add the Question objects into the ArrayList

That hardly make sense. The question returned will always be the one at `currentQuestionIndex` position. However, in the code you posted it is never incremented thus should always be 0. It seems like you forgot to post some important parts of your issue...

Still, if your goal is to simply retrieve them sequentially in the same order they are added you could get rid of the `currentQuestionIndex` by using a [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) and simply calling [`poll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#poll--) which will retrieve and remove the first element of the list thus each call will return the next one.

You could then get rid of this method :

```
public String getCurrentQuestion() {
    String question;
    questionBank.add(question1);
    questionBank.add(question2);
    questionBank.add(question3);
    question = questionBank.get(currentQuestionIndex).getQuestion();

    return question;
}
```

change it to something that make more sense (and call it only once i.e in the constructor)  :

```
public void addQuestions() {
    questionBank.add(question1);
    questionBank.add(question2);
    questionBank.add(question3);
}
```

and simply use `questionBank.poll();` to retrieve the next question. A call to `poll` will return `null` when the list is empty so you can easily handle when you are at the end of your list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I do have a method in the GUI class that gets called each time the user clicks the "Next" button that I deleted since my post was too long. The method increments the currentQuestionIndex and calls the getCurrentQuestion() method to set the text on the label and the getCurrentAnswers() method for displaying three possible answers on Radiobuttons.